# Java Axis faulstring

Tags: java, service, axis

I'm using Axis to generate a Web Service of a single method class.
That method instantiates another class that imports a librarys that are contained on a jar file I already added to the build path.

I've created a test class to test from the method and everithing works as expected.

By running the generated web service from a client I get an error string like this:

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>class on the jar file</faultstring>
```

I've tried placing the jar file on several places but with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is this: `class on the jar file` the error message or a place holder? The complete and exact error message would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Hey Andreas...

The class I'm instantiating (TestISeriesConnector) has for example an "import x.y.z".

The default string is just <faultstring>x.y.z</faultstring>

The console gives me:

WebServiceExc E org.apache.axis2.jaxws.WebServiceExceptionLogger log A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError throwable was caught.  The detail message is: at components.TestISeriesConnector.<init>(TestISeriesConnector.java:15)

The error doesn't help much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was quite simple.

The original project was part of an EAR project.

I just added the JAR file to the EAR project dependencies and voilá, problem solved (despite making sense of it the original project was already on the EAR project dependencies, but... whatever...)